# Pass sql result from controller to views in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm having a problem to get my data from controller into my view, and I was hoping someone could help me.

Here is the code for my controller:

```
$Info = new Info();
$Info = DB::select('SELECT * FROM 'tblinfo');
```

and I only echo it in controller because my value results doesn't pass into the view, here's the additional code for my controller:

```
foreach ($Info as $Infos)
{
 echo $Infos->fname;
 echo $Infos->gender;
}
$data['result'] = $Infos->fname;
$data['result'] = $Infos->gender;
$this->view =         View::make(App::make('web')->makeDeviceVersionPath('.').'.infofolder.infofile', $data);
```

Here is the code for my views:

```
@foreach $result as $info
 {{ $info->name }}
 {{ $info->gender }}
@endforeach
```

I hope someone could help me to pass my sql result to my views. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u have model u dont need to type raw sql code
just do like this

```
    $info= Info::all();
    return View('Index.index')->with('info',$info); // use ->with('*',$*) to send data to view
    //  Index is View folder
    //  .index is view name
```

Now in view grab $info data with for each

```
@foreach($info as $infodata)
<h3>{{ $infodata->name }}</h3>
<h3>{{ $infodata->gender}}</h3>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Adnan's answer is ok.

Op you should really check Eloquent and Response documentation from laravels website.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses